# How do I transpose a column values as headers but keep other columns as rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I would like to adjust a dataframe as per below. In the end I should add a total quantity summing all quantities name.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['product', 'sector', 'name', 'quantity'], 
                  data=[['pc', 'sector_x', 'John', 100],
                        ['pc', 'sector_x', 'Fred', 200],
                        ['tv', 'sector_y', 'John', 200],
                        ['tv', 'sector_y', 'Fred', 100],
                        ['tv', 'sector_x', 'John', 100],
                      ])
```

Desired Output:

```
product sector John Fred Total
pc sector_x 100  200 300
tv sector_y 200  100 300
tv sector_x 100  0 100
```